# NotificationCompat.Builder setLargeIcon doesnt show image in notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-bitmap

Im trying to show small icon in notification. Tried with several extensions. 
JPG, BMP, PNG, SVG.

It shows small icon when activity is running but when activity is not running it doesnt show small icon in notification.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_success);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(bitmap))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

I expect to see the image on the right side of notification.
I have placed those file both in drawable and in mipmap, no results.

[notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjtTq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a perfect square image? I mean, same width and height.
That maybe the issue.

I had shown a largeIcon with a 144x144 png image, and it works like a charm.

Comment: yes i did, dimensions were 512x512 so i reduced to 64x64 and still it doesnt show

Answer (score 0):

Android icons (and other UI elements, like drag lengths) are measured in dp. A dp is a device/density-independent pixel. 1 dp is equivalent to 1 px on a 160 dpi screen. But to convert to other screen densities, you need to multiply it by a density factor. So it's generally recommended that multiple images are supplied for most icons.

For example, the notification icons used in the status bar are specified as 24x24 dp, with a 1 dp margin (so the actual icon only takes up a 22x22 dp optical square, though some of the AA can bleed into that 1 dp margin/safeframe). To convert 24 dp to actual pixel sizes, these rough calculations are used:

```
display density  dp units * scale = px units
ldpi  ~120 dpi   24x24 dp * .75   = 18x18 px
mdpi  ~160 dpi   24x24 dp * 1.0   = 24x24 px
hdpi  ~240 dpi   24x24 dp * 1.5   = 36x36 px
xhdpi ~320 dpi   24x24 dp * 2.0   = 48x48 px
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to set Bitmap on style first

**NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        style.bigPicture(bitmap);**

Then use the above style on 

**setStyle(style)**

Comment: i have tried that it didnt changed, but still thanks

Comment: Add some delay while converting the image on bitmap then after send the notification